# How to omit the table join based on some condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

=======================

```
SELECT *
      FROM PRODUCT P
      JOIN PRODUCT_LOC PL
        ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PL.PRODUCT_ID

      JOIN PRODUCT_LOC_DEF PLD AND PL.LOC_ID = PLD.LOC_ID
      JOIN PRODUCT_CURRENT_LOC PCL
        ON PLD.LOC_ID = PCL.LOC_ID AND P.PRODUCT_ID = PCL.PRODUCT_ID
```

How should I modify the query to get expected result in case 1 and case 2 as given in attached snapshot?

Preferred:
I am looking for the modification in the same query instead of making two query and union them.

Comment: That's basically what an outer join does!

Comment: You said "If there exists no record in PRODUCT_CURRENT_LOC for a PRODUCT_ID ...Even then I want the query to bring the record"  What's the difference between that and what you just said outer join does?

Comment: Perhaps you need to update your question with an example of the data and the output you want.

Comment: @Tony Andrew, with left join I am getting unexpected record as shown in snapshot

Comment: Where is the table PRODUCT_LOC_DEF`in your example?

Comment: @ Marcus H , Something like  PRODUCT_LOC_DEF table is master table for Location Information. So here there are three records in this table (LOCID1,LOCID2 and LOCID3)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `left join` instead of an inner join:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM PRODUCT P
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_LOC PL ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PL.PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_LOC_DEF PLD AND PL.PRODUCT_LOC_ID = PLD.LOC_ID
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_CURRENT_LOC PCL ON PLD.LOC_ID = PCL.LOC_ID
```

Comment: Did you refer the problem mentioned in snapshot with left join? This will bring two records [PID1, LOCID1][PID1, LOCID2] even if LOCID1,LOCID2 are not there in PRODUCT_CURRENT_LOC table, as long as LOCID1,LOCID2 are in PRODUCT_LOC.. which is not expected one.Expected only one record [PID,NULL]

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    PRODUCT p
INNER JOIN 
    PRODUCT_CURRENT_LOC pcl
ON
    p.PRODUCT_ID = pcl.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN 
    PRODUCT_LOC pc
ON
    pc.LOC_ID = pcl.LOC_ID
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
    PRODUCT p
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PRODUCT_CURRENT_LOC pcl
ON
    p.PRODUCT_ID = pcl.PRODUCT_ID
    AND 
    pcl.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PRODUCT_LOC pc
ON
    pc.LOC_ID = pcl.LOC_ID
    AND 
    pc.LOC_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: **Suggestion:** Use [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) to do it in a SINGLE QUERY. @027

Comment: at the same time, I am looking for the performance of the query..may be table looked up twice as we have two query..